# Dispaly taxonomy terms in a content page in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I am a newbie in drupal. I'm working on project in drupal 7.
I wanted a page in which i want to show the content and taxonomy terms both one after the other.
First what i did is, created a page and added the content.
then, i have created a new taxonomy and its terms.
created some contents and related these to one taxonomy term, when i click the term, i can see the contents i related.
Now, what i wanted is, this term should be visible in the page i created. how to connect this page and taxonomy term?
this website has already two pages with different terms showing but i cant see any views created for those pages.

Comment: If I understand, Do you want to create a page that shows all your taxonomy terms?

Comment: yes also with the page content

Comment: not all, only one specific taxonomy term

Answer (score 0):

Okey, you hace to delete your page content created. The Views module creates your page.

You have to install the views module: https://drupal.org/project/views

Go to view->add new view
give title and in Show field select Taxonomy terms options and select the type and other info etc.. and click save
You created the taxonomy page.
Of course you have to create the filters to show only the taxonomy term you want.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can u please elaborate me how to show only the taxonomy i want???

Comment: You have to add a filter in the view. Go to FILTER CRITERIA, and choose the filter related with the taxonomy term name.

Comment: How to add the content den... I followed your steps but i'm get an empty page. the taxonomy terms has content related to it but i can see only header and footer but empty content in middle

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create a page(via add content->page) and that page to show taxonomy/tags its related to?
The problem is that pages only have title & body. So if you want the standard drupal page to show taxonomy or other fields for that matter, then you need to :

1.modify the basic page fields and add fields you want OR
2.Create content type of your own and add fields you want.

To do #1, you go to structure->content types -> pages -> manage or edit fields.

To do # 2 you go to structure->content types->add content type